# How to cancel tab panel switch in RichFaces 3.3.x

Tags: richfaces, tabpanel

I need to do some basic validation on a form. The form data is broken up among 5 tabs, and the user should be able to submit the form from any tab. So far so good. If the user hasn't filled in a field, or has entered invalid data I want to stay on the current tab, display an error message and cancel the tab switch.

I have tried the various events that I can find. Does anybody have any idea if this is possible and how I might achieve it? I would prefer to keep it on the client side in javascript if possible.

Using a code sample such as below.

```
<rich:tabPanel selectedTab="Info" switchType="client" contentClass="hz-record-tabpanel" ontabchange="doTabChange();"  onbeforeitemchange="doTabChange();" onbeforetabchange="doTabChange();">
                <rich:tab name="Info" label="Tab Label" onlabelclick="doTabChange();">
                    <ui:include src="info.xhtml" />
                </rich:tab>
                <rich:tab name="Officers" label="Officers" onlabelclick="doTabChange();" ontableave="doTabChange();">
                    <ui:include src="officers.xhtml" />
                </rich:tab>
                <rich:tab name="CardServices" label="Card Services" onlabelclick="doTabChange();">
                    <ui:include src="cardservices.xhtml" />
                </rich:tab> 
                <rich:tab name="M2MLimits" label="M2M Limits" onlabelclick="doTabChange();">
                    <ui:include src="m2mlimits.xhtml" />
                </rich:tab> 
                <rich:tab name="AccountServices" label="Account Services" onlabelclick="doTabChange();">
                    <ui:include src="accountservices.xhtml" />
                </rich:tab>                 
            </rich:tabPanel>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We eventually moved to Richfaces 4 (4.2) and I am successfully using `itemchange` and `beforeitemchange`

events.

These events fire twice (haven't figured that one out yet) so you don't want anything too intensive in the handler code.

If `beforeitemchange` returns false (twice) then the tabpanel will not switch.

I am using the `itemchange` event to fire any extra javascript to format data, and place focus on the first input field in the form on that tab.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of button I use to close a rich:modalPanel after a good validation :

```
<a4j:commandButton id="btnModify" value="Modifier" actionListener="#{editCityActions.onButtonModifyClick}" data="#{facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal ge 2}" oncomplete="if(event.data == false) { #{rich:component('frmEditCity')}.hide(); }" render="tblCities" />
```

I think you can apply an event with a4j:ajax or something like that!

Comment: I was hoping to keep it on the client side.

Comment: I've never used javascript to know if there are errors on validation (like facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal), but maybe there is something to do it. If I find something, I'll let you know!